# In combo box selection change, first selection returning all values as 0 and next selections returning the values of the previous row of the database

Tags: wpf, vb.net, sql-server-2008

i am loading one combo box with value from database.

when i am selecting the first option from the combo box, it's fetching all other values as 0, and when i am selecting the next option from the combo box it's showing the results of the previous option

Below is my code

This is for the combo box

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select CompanyName from Company", conn) 'Company Name
    Dim dt As New DataTable 'Company Name
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd) 'Company Name
    da.Fill(dt) 'Company Name

    'Company Name

    cmbCompanyName.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
    cmbCompanyName.DisplayMemberPath = "CompanyName"
    cmbCompanyName.SelectedValuePath = "CompanyName"
```

and below one is for filling the fields at combo selection changed

```
 Try

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=KITT7-PC;Initial Catalog=project;User ID=sa;Password=1234")
        connection.Open()

        Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand("select * from Company where CompanyName='" & cmbCompanyName.Text & "'", connection)
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd3)
        da.Fill(dt)

        If dt.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("More than one record found for the company name")
        End If

        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No records found")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        cmbCompanyCode.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
        txtCompanyCode.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible

        cmbComapnyAlias.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
        txtCompanyAlias.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            txtCompanyCode.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CompanyCode").ToString()
            '    txtCompanyName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CompanyName").ToString()
            txtCompanyAlias.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Alias").ToString()
            txtAddress.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Address").ToString()
            cmbCity.Text = dt.Rows(0)("city").ToString()
            txtPincode.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Pincode").ToString()
            cmbState.Text = dt.Rows(0)("State").ToString()
            txtCountry.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Country").ToString()
```

please tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your For Each loop you are always referencing `dt.Rows(0)("something")`, aren't you?

I guess you need to change:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            txtCompanyCode.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CompanyCode").ToString()
            '    txtCompanyName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CompanyName").ToString()
            txtCompanyAlias.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Alias").ToString()
```

to something like

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            txtCompanyCode.Text =  dr ("CompanyCode").ToString()
            '    txtCompanyName.Text =  dr ("CompanyName").ToString()
            txtCompanyAlias.Text =  dr ("Alias").ToString()
```

Comment: that sounds very strange. Anyway, does it work if you change your for loop to iterate with index and then use sth like
dt.Rows(i)."CompanyCode").ToString()?